# Calculate slope from ALOS Global Digital Surface Model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.5

I have downloaded the relevant tiles from [this model](http://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/aw3d30/) for the area I am studying, but cannot create meaningful slope data using the "Slope" tool of ArcGIS 10.5

I understand that the data requires projecting - I think the correct procedure is to use the UTM or Lambert projections due to the units being in arcseconds, however my study area covers multiple UTM grids leaving only Lambert an option (I think).

I tried projecting the raster from WGS 84 to "Europe_Lambert_Conformal_Conic" using the Coordinate Transformation: ED50 to WGS 84 (1), but this resulted in massively blown out of proportion data, perhaps due to an incorrect cell size? I used "Bilinear" over the "Nearest" resampling technique but didn't specify a cell size as I'm not sure how to work this out.

Comment: If you have the data as tiles, can you split them into sections for each UTM zone?  Have you tried mosaicking the tiles to a new raster before projecting?  You could mosaic all the tiles, then clip out each UTM zone, reproject, and calculate slope.